# Matlab error: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab, pde, heat

I am coding this function. I'm getting this error when running a function

Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts.
and I can't understand where's the error.

```
Lx = r;                
Ly = z;                

Nx = 20;                
Ny = Nx;                

dx = Lx/Nx;            
dy = Ly/Ny;            


k = 0.72;             
rho = 1920;             % Density (kg/m^3)
Cp = 835;               % Specific heat (J/kgK)
alpha = k/(rho*Cp);     % Thermal diffusivity (m^2/s)

deltaT = 1300;                          % Time step (seconds)
deltaT_stable_max = .25*dx.^2/alpha;     % Maximum stable time step
Fo = alpha*deltaT./dx.^2;                 % Fourier number 

T=(21:0.1:35)
T1 = T;                 % BC temperature 1 (deg. Celsius)
T2(1) = T(1);               % BC temperature 2 (deg. Celsius)

T = T1 %.*ones(Nx+1,Ny+1); % Initialize T array to T1 everywhere
T(1:Nx,Ny+1) = T2;      % Initialize top row to T2 boundary condition
T(1,Ny+1) = T2;      % Initialize top left
T(Nx+1,Ny+1) = T2;      % Initialize top right
Tplot = ones(Lmax,1);   % Initialize Tplot to allocate memory

x = 0:dx:Lx;            % Create x-distance node locations
y = 0:dy:Ly;            % Create y-distance node locations

for L = 1:Lmax          % Loop through time steps
    Told = T;           % Store previous T array as Told for next time step
    for j = 2:length(h)        % Loop through rows
        for i = 2:length(h)    % Loop through columns
            T2(i,j) = Fo*(Told(i-1,j) + Told(i+1,j) + Told(i,j-1)+ Told(i,j+1)) + (1-4*Fo)*Told(i,j);
        end   
    end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895343/assignment-has-more-non-singleton-rhs-dimensions-than-non-singleton-subscripts-e

Comment: MATLAB also tells you the line number that is at fault. Please post that as well.

Comment: Your code is also riddled with errors like variables not being defined. Please make sure those trivial errors are gone.

Comment: @Elly T2(i,j) = Fo*(Told(i-1,j) + Told(i+1,j) + Told(i,j-1)+ Told(i,j+1)) + (1-4*Fo)*Told(i,j);

Comment: This T2(i,j) is the error